# Error when running selenium test case using jenkins

Tags: java, linux, firefox, selenium, jenkins

Encountered the following error. Cannot identify the exact root cause.

Error Message

Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/lib64/firefox/firefox) on port 7055; process output follows: 
Error: cannot open display: :99
Error: cannot open display: :99

Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '32a636c', time: '2015-03-05 22:01:35'
System info: host: 'nila.ejyothi.net', ip: '192.168.202.35', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-229.20.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.7.0_91'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
Stacktrace

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/lib64/firefox/firefox) on port 7055; process output follows: 
Error: cannot open display: :99
Error: cannot open display: :99

Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '32a636c', time: '2015-03-05 22:01:35'
System info: host: 'nila.ejyothi.net', ip: '192.168.202.35', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-229.20.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.7.0_91'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:130)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
    at com.fetchinglife.application.modules.utilities.CommonFunctions.initBrowser(CommonFunctions.java:74)
    at com.fetchinglife.application.modules.employee.EmployeeScheduleFunctionalTest.StartBrowser_NavURL(EmployeeScheduleFunctionalTest.java:34)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
Error: cannot open display: :99
Error: cannot open display: :99

```
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is likely to happen when Selenium webDriver API can't load Firefox driver.
Possible cause could be compatibility between Firefox version and Selenium server version.

Use the latest Selenium Server 2.51.0